# How to get buttons background like a Toasts background?

Tags: background, shapes, shadow

How to get buttons background like this?
https://lh5.ggpht.com/SFGKlSzoUYd6eNYQnVynvM8EVUIWFzMYtkMXNY3c2aDCa6nwCmau6Wg6dv0XJcGa20w=h900-rw

Around the phrase

Comment: In what language? Although I'm going to assume Android, due to "Toast" mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Frame layout to get the overlapping imageview and button.

Set the background of the button to black and set alpha (transparency) value to the same.

Try it and post your code and result if you need further help!